# Hiding a column in angular material table

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm working with an Angular Material table that has a lot of columns, and I want to hide some of them specifically at certain CSS media queries.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Speed">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Speed</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="mat-cell">
    <span class="speed" [ngClass]="{ 'bold': selectedSpeedNames.includes(speed.name) }" *ngFor="let speed of row.speed.$values">{{ speed.name }}</span>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  th[mat-header-cell*="Speed"],
  td[mat-cell*="Speed"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

I've tried using the CSS media query to hide the "Speed" column on smaller screens (between 480px and 768px), but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The column is not being hidden as intended.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach to achieve this functionality? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Check [Material table docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#styling-columns) to target specific columns via their name in "matColumnDef"

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are including a column of data in your MatTable that doesn't need to show up? You shouldn't have to use css to do this either. If you look at the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api), you'll see all you have to do is not include the column names in the `matHeaderRowDef` on the `tr`. It is considered best practice to not have that column info in your definitions or header definitions if it's not needed. With that in mind, instead of using the css query to do that, you can wire up your component to listen for the screen size and remove the selected columns as you need to.

Here is what that might look like:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  if(event.target.innerWidth <= 480) {
       // logic to find the index of your "speed" column in your array
       this.matHeaderRowDefValues.splice(fndIndx, 1);
  } else if(event.target.innerWidth > 480) {
       // your logic to know what index to reinsert it back at
       this.matHeaderRowDefValues.splice(insertIndx, 0, "speed");
  }
}
```